# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code which works within the R interpreter as expected

```
recodeRule <- function(df, rules){
    for(i in 1:nrow(rules)){
        x <- which(df$key == rules$key[i] & df$score == rules[i, 'before'])
        df[x, 'score'] <- rules[i, 'after'] 
    }
    df
}
df <- data.frame(key = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), score = c(1,1,2,2,1,1))
rules <- data.frame(key = c(1,2), before = c(1,1), after = c(10,12))
recodeRule(df, rules)
```

However, when that same code is placed within my Shiny app, I get "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". The traceback shows:

```
Stack trace (innermost first):
    113: which [Rcode/serverFiles/testScoring.R#30]
    112: recodeRule [Rcode/serverFiles/testScoring.R#30]
    111: <reactive:stuItems4Scoring> [Rcode/serverFiles/testScoring.R#35]
    100: stuItems4Scoring
     99: get
     98: <reactive:dimVarNms> [Rcode/serverFiles/testScoring.R#132]
     87: dimVarNms
     86: lapply
     85: listify
     84: choicesWithNames
     83: selectInput
     82: tagAppendChild
     81: selectizeIt
     80: selectizeInput
     79: renderUI [Rcode/serverFiles/testScoring.R#137]
     78: func
     77: origRenderFunc
     76: output$dimVars4Scoring
      1: runApp
```

The function is embedded within this reactive expression. The expected behavior of this function is to read in and return a file. It would modify that file and return it if a second file is read in.

```
stuItems4Scoring <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$stuItems4Scoring != "", ""))    
    infile <- input$stuItems4Scoring
    if (!is.null(input$stuItems4Scoring)) {
        file <- load(input$stuItems4Scoring$datapath, e6)
    }
    ### Apply recode if requested
    if(!is.null(input$recodeRules)){
        rules <- recodeFile()
        file <- recodeRule(file, rules)
        return(file)
    } else {
        file
    }   
})
```

and the portion of code that reads in the `rules` file is as follows:

```
recodeFile <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$recodeRules != "", "")) 
    infile <- input$recodeRules
    if (is.null(infile)) return(NULL)      
    read.csv(infile$datapath)
})
```

If I do not read in the `recodeFile` then the relevant portions of the actual app work as expected as the original daatframe is returned. However, when I read in the `recodeFile`, what should happen is it should modify the data (as in the working example provided above working in the R interpreter) and return the modified file. This is where my code is failing and I'm not sure why.

The traceback is suggesting the offending line of code is in the `which` statement within the `recodeRule` function but I'm simply not seeing the reason why as I'm somewhat in the weeds at this point.

Thank you for any support.

Comment: Have shiny display the df and rules object while it is running. I bet you will be surprised by the result.  One of the two will be an atomic vector.

Comment: `load` does not return a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Shiny using rgl package. I used the renderRglwidget() function in the server.R and rglwidgetOutput() in the ui.r file.
This problem is then solved by adding a line to the end of the expr paramter of the renderRglwidget() function. The line is: `rglwidget()`